# Difference in Google MX record IPs and upper-lower case hostnames

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, google

Two different domains, both using Google Workspace.

Why are there different IPs for the same hostname, i.e. `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM` and `aspmx.l.google.com`?

Does this have to do with the upper/lower case difference?

Is one or the other (upper or lower case) preferred by Google?

[image: mx records screenshot]

[image: mx records screenshot]

Comment: No difference. Case doesn't matter in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because google does load balancing. Resolving the same name in different locations or at different times will give different results.

You should not pay attention to what response you get when querying DNS of companies that operate a network on a global scale. The answers simply doesn't make sense when interpreted in the manners of smaller networks, as google may employ tricks such as [anycast routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast).